# Gitlab pipeline failing with "No related merge requests found" when I push to master without a PR

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration

I make changes on master, push them up, and a gitlab pipeline runs.  But it fails with "No related merge requests found."  I'm using the hosted service / runners.

In the latest instance, I changed a number of files, including, `src/lib/api-proxy/package-lock.json`.  I think my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file should have triggered a rebuild:

```
trigger_api:
  stage: triggers
  trigger:
    include: src/.gitlab-ci.yml
    strategy: depend
  rules:
    - changes:
      - src/lib/**/*
      - src/api-proxy-lambda/**/*
```

`src/.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
build-lib-api-proxy:
  stage: build
  image: node:alpine
  script:
    - cd src/lib/api-proxy
    - npm install --verbose
    - npm run build
  cache:
    paths:
      - lib/api-proxy/node_modules/
  rules:
    - when: on_success
```